# Onsen UI postpop event is not firing

Tags: cordova, dom-events, onsen-ui

I am trying to use onsen ui in Cordova development.

```
      <body ng-controller="AppController" > 

    <!-- Navigator as root element -->
    <ons-navigator var="myNavigator" ng-controller="SubController" ons-prepush="onPopPost($event)" ons-postpop="onPopPost($event)"> 
        <ons-page>
            <ons-toolbar fixed-style>
                <div class="left"></div>
                <div class="center"><img src=""></div>
                <div class="right"></div>
            </ons-toolbar> 
           <ons-tabbar position="top">
            <ons-tabbar-item active="true" page="latest.html" id="latestTab">
              <div class="tab">
                <ons-toolbar-button class="tabmain" modifier="outline">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Latest&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="notificationLatest" class="notification" style="display:none">*</span></ons-button>
              </div>
            </ons-tabbar-item>    
    </ons-tabbar>  
     </ons-page>  
    </ons-navigator> 

 <ons-template id="latest.html">
      <ons-page ng-controller="MainPageController" fixed-style>  
 </ons-page>
  </ons-template>
```

In app.js I have

```
module.controller('AppController', function($scope,$timeout) {
$scope.onPopPost = function(event) {
        console.log("sad");
        console.log(event.enterPage);

      }
```

The event is not firing.
As per the documentation this is supported. But I could not see this event firing.
Is there any other settings I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your navigator has the `postpop` handler but you are not pushing a page in the navigator. You are changing pages in the tabbar and those are different components. Use these events instead: http://onsen.io/reference/ons-tabbar.html#attributes

```
<ons-tabbar ng-controller="AppController" ons-postchange="onPopPost($event)" position="top">
   ...
</ons-tabbar>
```

Working here:
http://codepen.io/frankdiox/pen/NqOELO

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I see the code is working in the codepen. But this is not firing in my project. I will create a minimal codepen code and send you the link. There is a ng-click I have added for the content inside one tab item. On Click of it I am using the code myNavigator.pushPage('launcher.html', { animation : 'lift' } ); there is a close button on the launcher.html. in that I am calling myNavigator.popPage('launcher.html'); none of these are firing any events

Comment: Fran Dios, added the code here. [http://codepen.io/kirant400/pen/jPeRNo](http://codepen.io/kirant400/pen/jPeRNo). if I add angular.module('app', ['onsen', 'ngSanitize']); code is not working. and tab events are working but not the push events

Comment: `myNavigator.pushPage()` is working well. It is firing an event, I can see it on the console. However, you have a problem with Angular controllers in `launcher.html`. That page has no controller so when you call `closeLaunch()` nothing happens.